# Installing packages with pip in command prompt are throwing errors

Tags: python

I am trying to install Python packages with pip in command window. However, I am facing the following errors.

```
C:\Users\sidra aleem>pip install matplotlib
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in c:\users\sidra aleem\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (2.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\users\sidra aleem\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2018.3)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\users\sidra aleem\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10 in c:\users\sidra aleem\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\users\sidra aleem\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in c:\users\sidra aleem\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\users\sidra aleem\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7.1 in c:\users\sidra aleem\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.14.3+mkl)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\sidra aleem\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib) (28.8.0)
```

and for numpy

```
C:\Users\sidra aleem>pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\sidra aleem\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (1.14.3+mkl)
```

The version of Python I am using is 3.6.4.on window 10.

Comment: These are not errors, it simply means these packages are already installed in your system (see `Requirement already satisfied`). You can import these packages and use them.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this doesn't mean something is wrong. Just check if you can use the packages. 
Or you try uninstalling and reinstalling the packages.